# Nav tag not rendering correctly in Angular 2 and mdl

Tags: angular, material-design, angular2-routing

Hi i'm a bit new to mdl and i'm having a issue with how a nav bar is being rendered in a angular 2 web app i'm building - it's rendering as a grey background and hover- [image: angular 2 web app]
if i take it out of the nav it renders ok but i'm not sure how to add the mdl responsiveness without it..

below is the html template i'm using

```
    <div mdl class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header hpe-slate mdl-layout__header--waterfall">
    <div class="mdl-layout-icon"></div>
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <!-- Title -->
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">angular2-quickstart</span>
      <!-- Add spacer, to align navigation to the right -->
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <!-- Navigation. We hide it in small screens. -->
      <nav class="mdl-navigation mdl-layout--large-screen-only">
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/Home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/Items" routerLinkActive="active">Items</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/Widgets">Widgets</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div class="mdl-layout__drawer mdl-layout--small-screen-only">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Menu</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/Home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/Items" routerLinkActive="active">Items</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" routerLink="/Widgets">Widgets</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <main class="mdl-layout__content">
    <div class="page-content">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
      <!-- Your content goes here -->
    </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: can you share your custom css as well

Answer (score 0):

ok sorry found the issue there was a rouge css with a background color set for the  nav a - removed a fixed the issue.